# Renaming ROIs in ImageJ based on their x coordinate value in order to create a sequence

Tags: macros, coordinates, rename, imagej, roi

After I few hours of intensive search, I need to ask you.

So, I few days ago I was provided with macro that effectively creates ROIs based on radius and function (Maximum). 
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22308224/automatically-recognized-objects-transferred-into-rois-in-imagej)

My starting point is the following image:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/65873264/Image.jpg

The problem is: I need to have ROIs sorted by sequence; (from left to right on an image). So I could easily rename them with macro and assign appropriate year. As you can see on provided image with link; scanning while creating ROIs goes from up to down, therefore the tallest ROI gets number 1.

So I would like to rename each ROI based on X coordinate (ROI Manager, List). I really can’t figure out how to call x coordinate… And here I need your help. Later I will sort ROIs and rename them again (years by sequence).

Alternatively, could I modify Analyze particle function in order to change the scanning direction?

I am beginner in programming, very motivated, but I need help from experienced fellas. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

So, here is the solution of problem described in my question:

```
run("Set Measurements...", "  centroid redirect=None decimal=9");
for (i=0 ; i<roiManager("count"); i++) {
    roiManager("select", i);
    roiManager("Measure");
    x = getResult("X",0);
    roiManager("Rename", x);
    run("Clear Results");
}

roiManager("Sort");
selectWindow("Results");
run("Close");
```